# Problem with geotiff in qgis only in some PCs

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

Helllo

I'm having some weird problem opening a 16bits geotiff with qgis. In my pc it opens and displays perfectly, but in another pc (with the same version of qgis) it displays all wrong
the image getting pixels of several colors without any sense.

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Might be worth to try gdal-info on both rasters, in each computer. That will probably shed some light on the problem. It's in the Raster->Miscellaneous->Information menu

Comment: Hm, any color table associated with that raster? Maybe in an extra file which didn't get passed along?